# How to post the value of all radio groups on page in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I trying to make a simple image gallery, where I have several radio button groups to filter the search results.(I am pretty new to jquery, and started learning it today, so please be patient.)

1)I have tried this code to create an associative array, but the array comes up as blank. Any ideas?

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
        searchCriteria[this.name]=this.value;
    });
```

2)Along with that, can someone show me how to post the data to a php page( using jQuery ajax), using POST method?
Will this work?

```
$.post('testResults.php',searchCriteria,displayResult);
```

To every one trying to help:
The following code seems to work

```
    $('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
        searchCriteria.push(new addValue(this.name,this.value));
        //searchCriteria['this.name']=this.value;
    });

function addValue(a,b)
{
    this.key=a;
    this.val=b;
};
```

But that creates an object array.....why am I having problems creating the associative array?

Comment: Have you defined `searchCriteria` before the call to `each()`?

Comment: Looks like it could work. Are you sure, the DOM is ready when you're calling the code? Any JS errors?

Comment: @lonesomeday: yeh it is defined as searchCriteria=new Array().
@AndreKR: I don't get any errors. I am tracking things with firebug, and things seem normal.

Comment: There's no such thing as an associative array in JS.  You need to use objects instead. These have key-value pairs just like associative arrays in PHP, for instance.

Comment: Ah ok, but then how I make the array like that? instead of an array of objects? and how do I $.post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var searchCriteria = {},
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
    searchCriteria[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

ok, could be useful for you this output to send ajax?

```
var searchCriteria = $('input:radio:checked').serialize();
```

Comment: The OP's suggestion of `searchCriteria[this.name] = this.value;` is much better.

Comment: that too comes up as blank. And I don't think fetching is the problem, because the following code works:
$('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
        searchCriteria.push(new addValue(this.name,this.value));
        //searchCriteria['this.name']=this.value;
    });
function addValue(a,b)
{
    this.key=a;
    this.val=b;
};

But this creates an object array, I wonder why I can't create an object array?

PS: sorry I don't know how to type code in comment